# Correct folder structure for sites

Tags: html

I've just started tidying up the server for a particular site and am running into some trouble when moving files.

I originally had *style.css* in my **main folder**, and another folder called **images**, so paths in the *.css* went *images/myimage.png*

Now I have moved *style.css* into another folder called **css**.

So the image links in the CSS no longer work, as it's looking for the folder **images** from **it's own CSS folder**.

I changed the file path to */images/myimage.png* as I thought this would make it climb up a level and then look for the **images** folder, but this doesn't seem to work.

I'm interested to see what solutions people have and also any suggestions on how people organise their folders for a particular site.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to use a relative path like `../` ?

Comment: `/images/myimage.png` will mean `http://whateverTheSiteDomainIs/images/myimage.png`, to "climb up one" you want `../images/myimage.png`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do this ../images/myimage.png

This should work, for each level you want to go up, add ../

Answer (score 1):

Primary resources I structure in a way that will give some sort of mnemonic to the client process. E.g. if I have a bunch of resources representing employees, I'd put each at `/employees/alice`, `/employees/bob`, etc. If I have a resource representing all employees (a list etc.) I'd put it at `/employees/`, but if I didn't I'd still use that structure.

If this hierarchy is relatively simple, I'll follow it in terms of where I place the files.

If modelling something that is in itself hierarchical, I'd follow that hierarchy in the URI mapping. E.g. `/ireland/leinster/coDublin/dublin`. In this case I'd rather have the handler somewhere that doesn't have a direct correspondence to the path, like in `wwwroot\placesHandler`, as following it a bit, but not fully is less clear than obviously not following it.

For secondary resources like images, css, etc that are just part of rendering an entity rather than of primary interest to the client process, (most common on browser-focused human-readable sites). I normally just have an `/s/` an `/i/` and a `/js/` and go with the fact that by default pretty much all webservers will mirror the directory structure of your files in the path-structure of the site. Within those I'll group `/i/` and perhaps `/js/` according to purpose.

And as I said in the comments, `/images/myimage.png` will mean `http://whateverTheSiteDomainIs/images/myimage.png`, to "climb up one" you want `../images/myimage.png`.